# Whole image won't be drawn on canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a photo editor, where you have the option to upload an image that will be drawn on a canvas. I let the user upload a new image without refreshing the website. However, the second time you try to upload a different image, the whole image won't be drawn on the canvas. The only part that will be drawn is the size of the image that the user uploaded before that. This is pretty weird as a new size is set every time the user uploads a new image.

After some trial and error, I found out that the new canvas size is actually set to the size of the image that is uploaded. However, it still doesn't draw the whole image, even though it is specified that the image should be drawn at the size of the canvas. Therefore, it is a problem lying in the line that draws the image, and not the part that sets the size of canvas. I tried drawing the image twice instead of once just to see what would happen. It actually worked, even though the the two lines for drawing the image are identical. I found this pretty strange, and I feel like this is not the right way to fix it.

Here is the part of the code that loads the image:

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img;
var ratio;

var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay")

canvas.width = 400;

function handleImage(e){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ratio = this.height / this.width;
      canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    overlay.style = "display: none;"
    img.src = event.target.result;
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return true;
    };
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="imageLoader">
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<div id="overlay">Unrelated overlay...</div>
```

Comment: I made a live snippet from what you gave, but this doesn't permit to reproduce the claimed issue. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ditch the unnecessary FileReader and just do `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])`

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're getting is not weird but makes perfect sense because you’re supposed to adjust the size of the canvas to the NATURAL dimesnions of the image loaded each time!

What makes you think that the canvas automatically adjusts itself to any image loaded?

You need to do this with every new image load...

```
canvas.width=img.naturalWidth;
canvas.height=img.naturalHeight;
canvas.style.transform='scale(0.5,0.5)';
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understood my post. I use a ratio to proportionally scale the canvas to any size with the dimensions of the image. And I have checked if the canvas is resized to the image, and it is. However, the drawn image doesn't fill up the whole canvas, and the image looks cropped.

Comment: If were to scale an element including a canvas, I'd just use... canvas.style.transform='scale(x,y)'; Don’t scale things manually, let the computer do the calculations for you!

Comment: That is beside my question. There are many methods for setting the size of the canvas. What I am curious about is why the ctx won't fill up the whole canvas when it is set to the size of the canvas, and the canvas has the same dimensions as the image.

Comment: Don’t scale things manually, let the computer do the calculations for you!

Answer (score -1):

After some time, I found out that I had to use `clearRect` before redrawing the image.

Now the JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img;
var ratio;

var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay")

canvas.width = 400;

function handleImage(e){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
      ratio = this.height / this.width;
      canvas.height = canvas.width * ratio;
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    overlay.style = "display: none;"
    img.src = event.target.result;
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return true;
    };
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: No, setting the canvas width or height, even to the same values, will reset the context and clear its bitmap buffer, `clearRect` doesn't help at all here. Please edit your question so that we can reproduce the issue there.

Comment: I tried making a shortened version, but it didn't work for some reason. However, clearRect seems to have solved it for me, because everything works perfectly fine now.

Comment: And I bet that if you comment that clearRect line it will still work. Once again, this clearRect is a no-op here since you changed the canvas height.